# Shell command to calculate certain % of disk size

Tags: shell

I am writing shell script to calculate 15% of total disk size of user's home directory. I have this command which gets me(somewhat) what I want but not sure if there is better way of doing this.

```
df -hT /home/user1 | grep -vE '^Filesystem' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

this command outputs:

> `<blank line>`
>
> 516G

how do I extract 516 is my question if this command is right way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this in `awk` without grep:

```
df -hT /home/user | awk '$1 ~ "sda1"{gsub(/[A-Z]/,"",$4); print $4}'
```

The test on the front of the awk block `$1~"sda1"` is just checking to see that your main hard drive is the one that `df` is looking at. This is a lot safer than grabbing `df` records that don't contain `filesystem` which may spit out more than just your main drive if you stick another drive in the box, or mount some NFS drives.

`gsub(/[A-Z]/, "", $4)` just replaces out any capital letters in `$4` (the size of the drive) with nothing `""`. That should suffice since, I believe, all of the disk size suffixs (K, M, G, etc..) are capital letters. After that's done, we print the new and improved `$4`.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `$2+0` to make it a number in `awk`.
- You don't need `grep` as you can perform search in `awk` itself.

You can use:

```
df -hT / |  awk '/^Filesystem/{ print ($2+0) * 15/100 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of trying to remove 'G', you instead specify the block size.  This will ensure that you don't have to deal with the complication of being returned something like *M* or *K*:

```
df -BG /home/user1 | awk 'NR==2 { print $3 * 0.15 }'
```

Perhaps using -B1 is better, then do the human printable version manually:

```
df -B1 /home/user1 | awk 'NR==2 { split("K M G T P E", s); for(n=int($3*0.15); n>1024; n=rshift(n,10)) i++; print n s[i] }'
```

The above should be valid for (GNU coreutils) 8.12 and 8.25 versions of `df`.

The `df` output provides information about the partition that the given directory uses... which may work well if each of your users is graced with a partition of their own.  However, in large organizations especially it is more likely that `quota` is being used on your users directories.  Please consult the `man` pages for `quota` (and friends) if this is the case.

Comment: thanks Michael, this worked for me.                                                                    df -BG /home/user1 | awk 'NR==3 { print $1 * 0.15 }'

Comment: @Manth -- How did you end up with NR==3 in your case?  Maybe I should look to see if I can improve my answer?  The reason that I used NR==2 is that in my case, the header is on row 1 and the next row is the output... do you have any messages showing up on row 2? How also did $1 work for you? I am using "df  (GNU coreutils) 8.12" and "df (GNU coreutils) 8.25" from suse and ubuntu (respectively).